# Remove a consumer in RabbitMQ with nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, rabbitmq, sails.js

I am trying to my listener to listen the queue only 1 message after what i want to remove my consumer instantly. How can i achieve this.
here is the code.

```
  queueListener:function(Queue,timeOut){
    var deferred=sails.promise.defer(),timer,data;
    sails.amqp.connect('amqp://localhost', function(err, conn) {
      conn.createConfirmChannel(function(err, ch) {
        if(err){
          conn.close();
          deferred.reject(err);
        }else{
          ch.assertQueue(Queue, {durable: true});
          ch.prefetch(1);
          ch.consume(Queue,function(msg){
            data=msg.content.toString();
            clearTimeout(timer);
            ch.ack(msg);
            setTimeout(function(){
              conn.close();
              deferred.resolve(data);
            },0);
          },{noAck: false});
        }
      });
      timer=setTimeout(function(){
        conn.close();
        deferred.reject(new Error("Nothing in the Queue."));
      },timeOut-5);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
  }
```

in the above **Queue** is the queue it will be listening and timeOut represents how long my listener will be listening.
If it listens a message i want to stop listening.And for further listening i will be invoking the function **queueListner** next time.
Though i have made `conn.close()` but at the UI it still shows consumer.
[image]

Comment: You can also ask on the RabbitMQ-users group at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rabbitmq-users, also check release notes for fixed bugs (in case you are using an older version)

Comment: I have asked there https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rabbitmq-users/VlSKlfSWT7g
 but if anyone have a solution please share.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

don't use `consume`. if you only need to get a single message, use the `get` method

http://www.squaremobius.net/amqp.node/channel_api.html#channel_get

```
ch.get("queue-name").then(messageHandlerFunction)
```

this will retrieve a single message from the specified queue and run it through the specified message handler function

Comment: Will i need to close the connection if i use get method.

Comment: yes. the connection is separate from anything you do on the channel. you will still have to manage the connection the same way

Comment: Thanks @Derick
That helped me a lot.

Comment: i receive TypeError: cb is not a function